# Error acquiring the state lock: resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

when i am running terraform apply from my local i am getting this error .
i have also checked that no process is going on in terraform but still getting this error.

```
Error: Error locking state: Error acquiring the state lock: resource temporarily unavailable
Lock Info:
ID:        9b3a1535-a936-fd2c-64e1-5fde7b227737
Path:      terraform.tfstate
Operation: OperationTypeApply
Who:       dhaval.shah@DhavalShah.local
Version:   0.13.0
Created:   2021-05-21 20:54:48.108408 +0000 UTC
Info:
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check.

Are you reaching out to a storage bucket that holds your state, if so are you passing in the correct `bucket` and `prefix` fields?

Did you previously run through an `apply` step with that same state and have to terminate the operation early? If so there may be a `default.tflock` in the same `prefix` folder as the `default.tfstate` file. You can manually go into your storage bucket and delete the `.tflock` file or follow these [steps](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/locking.html).

Answer (score 0):

Generally this happens if your host is out of cpu or memory. Check if any of them is at limit other thing could be if you have a lot of ssh connection that can also cause this.